# Duplicate answer deleted, but can't close as duplicate

Tags: discussion

A mod [deleted my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58829687/174777) to a Question, stating *"Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions."*

However, when I try to mark it as duplicate ([original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54915531/174777)) I get the message:

> This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer.

What would be the proper thing for me to do in this situation?

Should I merely put a link to the original question via a comment?

Comment: Upvote the original answer then mark as duplicate, simples!

Comment: @Paulie_D Well, except that John, being the author, can't upvote that answer.

Comment: Well, in response to this question, it appears that somebody provided an upvote, so now I have marked it as a duplicate. (Thank you!) Was that the best way to achieve it?

Comment: add a comment to say that it's a duplicate and *hope* that someone upvote you. If it's really a duplicate you will most like get an upvote to allow the closure.

Comment: looks like someone gave your answer an upvote, so you're free to start dupe-voting.